# How to redirect URL by routes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to redirect this url:

```
mydomain.com/Param1-Param2Place
```

to

```
mydomain.com/Param1-Place-Param2
```

I want to use `routes` in Rails, don't want to use nginx, htaccess,...
Something like this:

```
get "/:param1", to: redirect("/%{param1}-Place")
```

Can someone help me out. 
I am using Ruby 2.x and Rails 4.x. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked here? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html

Comment: Thanks @sebkomianos. i looked there but in this case i don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

`get '/:param1', to: redirect { |params, request| "/#{params[:param1]}-Place-#{params[:param2]}" }`

Comment: Thanks! But in my case, i want to redirect
`mydomain.com/Param1-Param2Place` (if the url include the word "Place")
to
`mydomain.com/Param1-Place-Param2`
If the url don't include the word "Place", do nothing.